# is there any way to change author name, Author Initials in pptx file, using Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint

Tags: c#, .net, powerpoint, vsto

I'm currently working on a project using VSTO (Visual Studio Tools for Office). I'm adding comments from the backend to a PowerPoint (pptx) file using Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.

However, I'm facing an issue where the username of the user logged into the PowerPoint application is displayed when posting comments from the backend. My requirement is to add a custom author name for comments that I am posting from the backend.

I am using below code.

```cs
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Comment comment = slide.Comments.Add(
  Left: 0, Top: 0, Author: apiAuthor, AuthorInitials: apiAuthor, Text: title + "\n \n" + description);
```

I have checked Comment interface of Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint

```
     [DispId(2003)]
     string Author
     {
     [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
     [DispId(2003)]
     [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
     get;
     }

    [DispId(2004)]
    string AuthorInitials
    {
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
    [DispId(2004)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
    get;
    }
```

for Author and AuthorInitials only get property present. Not set property.

Comment: When you `Add` the comment you can specify an author https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.comments.add

Comment: see I am using code.




Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Comment comment = slide.Comments.Add(
 Left: 0, Top: 0,"ANT", "AN", Text: title + "\n \n" + description);

still not reflecting in pptx file.

Comment: Getting error while using above code  -




Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1744 Named argument 'Author' specifies a parameter for which a positional argument has already been given.

Comment: in above code "ANT" is related to Author name and "AN" is related to author Initial.

Comment: Sorry missed that mix of named and positional, rather unusual. Notes in the docs say "This method is now hidden. It will continue to work in existing places but cannot be added to new places in code. For modern comments, this method can only attribute comments to the signed-in user, not anyone passed in through the “author” field. To attribute modern comments to other authors, please update your calls to the Add2." So try `Add2`

Comment: I tried with 

 Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Comment comment = slide.Comments.Add2(
 Left: 0, Top: 0,Author:"ANT",AuthorInitials:"ANT", Text: title + "\n \n" + description,null,null);

But no luck

Comment: comment.Author= dynamicAuthorName;

getting compile time error - 
Error CS0200 Property or indexer 'Comment. Author' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only.